# Problem in uploading .dsym file using MAC terminal

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, terminal, crashlytics

I am getting below connection error problem in terminal, Anyone please provide me right suggestion how can we resolve this network related problem when I am uploading .dsym using terminal.

**Command:**
*/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios {/Desktop.zip}*

**ERROR:**
*error: Could not fetch upload-symbols settings: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.*

Comment: Resolved by me after discussing with @Firebase support

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following command instead:

```
/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp
 /GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /dSYM_folder/*.dsym
```